# Como puedo detener unos segundos las iteraciones de un bucle en java?

Tags: java, bucles, jtextfield

Tengo un bucle en java que muestra unos mensajes en un JTextField.
Lo que pasa es que uso un bucle para imprimirlo pero los imprime demasiado rapido y al final solo se termina viendo el que se imprimio de ultimo, intente usar Thread.Sleep Pero solo hace que se demore mas empezar el bucle y sigue mostrando los mensajes rapido.

```
private void btnCombateMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
    
   this.txtMensajes.setText("Los Personajes Atacaran!");
    for (int i = 0; i < (Jugadores.length-1); i++) {
        if (Jugadores[i].getVida() > 0){
            int Daño = Jugadores[i].getAtaque()-Bahamut.getBossDefensa();
            Bahamut.setBossVida(Bahamut.getBossVida() - (Daño));
            txtMensajes.setText(Jugadores[i].getNombre() + " Ha atacado! Daño: " + Integer.toString(Daño));
        }
        this.lblVidaJefe.setText(Integer.toString(Bahamut.getBossVida()));
       try {
           TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
       } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Combate.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
    }
}
```

Comparto el codigo. Agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Quizas te pueda servir esto armar una función con la cuenta regresiva y la llamas donde queres retrasar el tiempo esta función es de 10 seg.

```
public class CuentaRegresiva
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
            for(int i=10; i>0; i--)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
                try
                {
                      Thread.sleep(1000);
                        }catch(InterruptedException e){}
            }
    }
}
```